# Referencing a class that inherits from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reference

I am creating a library and i am referencing from class Main which inherits from Body

`public class Main:Body`

i added Main to my using references but when i go to initiate an instance - i tried:

`Main _main = new Main()` it underlines `new Main()` saying that it doesn't contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

How can i properly adjust that so i am referencing the class - do i need to included the inherited class as well?

Comment: Make a constructor ... `public Main()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Main _main = new Main()` it underlines new `Main()` saying that it doesn't contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

It's telling you exactly what the problem is. There isn't a public constructor on `Main` that takes zero arguments.

You need to do one of the following:

1. Add a public constructor that takes zero arguments: `public Main() { }`.
2. Invoke a different constructor that is public on the `Main` class: if the signature is `public Main(object o)` then you'd say `Main _main = new Main(o)` where `o` is some object.

Let's look at an example:

```
class Foo {
    public Foo() { }
}
```

This class has a public constructor with zero arguments. Therefore, I can construct instances via

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Let's look at another example:

```
class Bar {
    public Bar(int value) { }
}
```

This class does *not* have a public constructor with zero arguments. Therefore, I can *not* construct instances via

```
Bar bar = new Bar(); // this is not legal, there is no such constructor
                     // the compiler will yell
```

But I *can* say

```
Bar bar = new Bar(42);
```

Here's one more:

```
class FooBar { }
```

This class *does* have a public constructor with zero arguments. It does because if you do *not* provide *any* constructors, the compiler will automatically provide a public constructor with zero arguments *by default*. Thus, this is legal:

```
FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
```

Comment: so if i have `public class Main:Body` where body has a constructor taking 0 arguments - i could use `Body body = new Body()` and will i still be able to access methods in `Main`?

Comment: @loop852: No. Look at it like this. `public class SiameseCat : Cat`, and `Cat` has a zero-argument public constructor. `Cat cat = new Cat();` Can I access the methods of `SiameseCat`? No, because not all `Cat`s are `SiameseCat`s.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination - i was able to find my solution by passing in the required parameters. Thanks a bunch